# Monster Buff/Debuff System Design

Tags: java, object-oriented, game, role-playing-game

Below are a collection of classes that compose my buff/debuff system. The largest flaw in my design that I couldn't overcome is the base class `Effect` having an `enum` filled with the different types of buffs and debuffs. If there is a workaround that could clean up that part of the code I'd be really grateful. Otherwise, I'm simply looking for suggestions on potential bugs, mishaps, inefficient methods, etc.

The base class for `Effect`s

```
public abstract class Effect {

    public static enum Type { NIL, ATTACKBUFF, ATTACKBREAK, DEFENSEBUFF, DEFENSEBREAK }

    private Effect.Type type;

    public Effect(Effect.Type type) {

        this.type = type;

    }

    public abstract void apply();
    public abstract void expire();
    public abstract void update();

    public static Effect newEffect(Effect.Type type, Monster monster, int duration) {

        Effect effect;

        switch(type) {
        default:
        case NIL:
            effect = new NilEffect();
            break;
        case ATTACKBUFF:
            effect = new AttackBuff(monster, duration);
            break;
        case ATTACKBREAK:
            effect = new AttackBreak(monster, duration);
            break;
        case DEFENSEBUFF:
            effect = new DefenseBuff(monster, duration);
            break;
        case DEFENSEBREAK:
            effect = new DefenseBreak(monster, duration);
            break;
        }

        return effect;

    }

    public Effect.Type getType() {

        return type;

    }

}
```

A class for specific `StatModifier`s

```
abstract class StatModifier extends Effect {

    protected final Monster monster;
    protected final Stat originalStat;
    protected final Stat.Type statType;
    protected final double modifier;

    private int duration;

    public StatModifier(Monster monster, Effect.Type effectType, Stat.Type statType, double modifier, int duration) {

        super(effectType);

        this.monster = monster;
        this.statType = statType;
        originalStat = monster.getStat(statType);
        this.modifier = modifier;
        this.duration = duration;

    }

    @Override
    public void apply() {

        final int augmentedBaseStatValue = (int) Math.ceil(originalStat.getAugmentedStat() * modifier);
        final Stat stat = new Stat(augmentedBaseStatValue, 0, 0);
        monster.setStat(statType, stat);

    }

    @Override
    public void expire() {

        monster.setStat(statType, originalStat);

    }

    @Override
    public void update() {

        duration--;

        if(duration <= 0) {

            expire();

        }

    }

}
```

An example of a `StatModifier` class

```
public final class AttackBuff extends StatModifier {

    public AttackBuff(Monster monster, int duration) {

        super(monster, Effect.Type.ATTACKBUFF, Stat.Type.ATTACK, 1.5 ,duration);

    }

}
```

The `Monster` class (partial)

```
public class Monster {

    private final Map<Effect.Type, Effect> effects;

    public Monster() {

        effects = new HashMap<>();

    }

    public void addEffect(Effect.Type type, int duration) {

        if(effects.containsKey(type)) {

            effects.get(type).expire();
            effects.remove(type);

        }

        Effect effect = Effect.newEffect(type, this, duration);
        effect.apply();
        effects.put(effect.getType(), effect);

    }

    public void updateEffects() {

        effects.values()
               .parallelStream()
               .forEach(effect -> 

                   effect.update()

               );

    }

}
```

Comment: One tiny suggestion would be, since this is Java, you could have the entire Effect class be an enum instead of an enum within a class. Enums are classes in Java, so you can have methods within them. In that way, it would be much like an [algebraic data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Visibility modifiers and names

`enum` types are by default `public static`. You can choose to remove them.

`Type` is a very broad name for your `enum`, so you can consider just calling it `EffectType`.

#### `switch` and `return`

Instead of assigning the result to `effect`, you should `return` directly from each `case`, i.e.:

```
switch(type) {
case ATTACKBUFF:
    return new AttackBuff(monster, duration);
case ATTACKBREAK:
    return new AttackBreak(monster, duration);
case DEFENSEBUFF:
    return new DefenseBuff(monster, duration);
case DEFENSEBREAK:
    return new DefenseBreak(monster, duration);
// shifted default case as the last, it's more 'conventional'
default:
// case NIL:
    return new NilEffect();
}
```

You can also choose to place this as method for `EffectType` instead, but from an OOP approach, this depends if an `EffectType` is supposed to 'know' an `Effect` (and `Monster`) or not. Your approach is still fine.

#### Adding and updating effects

Since you are on Java 8, you can consider `return`-ing `null` from [`Map.computeIfPresent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfPresent-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) to expire the type and remove the entry in one go:

```
public void addEffect(Effect.Type type, int duration) {
    effects.computeIfPresent(type, (k, effect) -> { effect.expire(); return null; });
    Effect effect = Effect.newEffect(type, this, duration);
    effect.apply();
    effects.put(effect.getType(), effect);
}
```

Do you really need to invoke `parallelStream()` when updating effects? Since the maximum number of elements you can have in your `Map` is bounded by the number of `EffectType` values (BTW, you may want to switch to an [`EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html)), I think the overhead of doing a concurrent access on your `Map` is not required. Also the `forEach()` operation can be done using a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) as well, in this case:

```
public void updateEffects() {
    effects.values().stream().forEach(Effect::update);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Is there an argument against being explicit with my public/static declarations? I prefer to keep the name as Type and access the enum through scope (Effect.Type). I see no reason to prefer naming it as EffectType, it's effectively the same thing. The returns in place of the assignments in the switch statement are also just semantics in my opinion and i see no real benefit of my current approach over the other. I agree with the parallel stream case, along with implementing the update method as a method reference.

Comment: The point about visibility modifiers is also down to personal preferences, to me it's just a matter of non-repetition. :)